# Why does the variance term in the VICREG paper encourage the variance to be equal to γ?

Tags: regularization, hinge-loss

In section 4.1 of the [VICreg paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.04906.pdf) the authors describe the variance regularization term as the following hinge loss.
$$ v(Z) = \frac{1}{d}\sum_{j=1}^{d}max(0, \gamma - S(z^j, \epsilon )) $$

- Z being the embedding of an image of shape $ \mathbb{R}^{(n, d)} $
- S being a "safe" standard deviation (which uses a small constant $ \epsilon $).
- $ \gamma $ being set to a constant 1

After that they state: "*This criterion encourages the variance inside the current batch to be equal to γ along each dimension, preventing collapse with all the inputs mapped on the same vector*".

My question is, why / how does this variance term encourages $ v $ to be equal to $ \gamma $ (1 in this case)? I would assume that minimizing $ v(Z) $ would result in having a large standard deviation (S >> $ \gamma $) and that this would lead to the hinge loss being 0, instead of 1.